# Python 3.2 installation using UCS-4 environment

Tags: 10.04, python

I building applications using Qt4 to develop the UI and python 3.2
OS UBUNTU 10.04
Python 3.2 is installed but fails the following

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    from PyQt4.QtGui import *
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/PyQt4/QtCore.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_AsLatin1String
```

I've attempted to install python to use UCS-4 but have not been able to do so.
Python 2.6 on the machine performs without a problem import objects/modules from Qt4.

How do I go about configuring Python 3.2 to work in UCS-4 environment?

Comment: I think Ubuntu compiled Pythons have wrong UCS-4 setting and you need to build your own if you want to change it.